# R Shiny and Tensorflow in Docker

Tags: r, docker, tensorflow, shiny

I am trying to dockerise my R shiny application. The application depends on python tensorflow and keras. but I am unable to get tensorflow in my R environment

My `Dockerfile`

```
# Pull Ubuntu Image Configured with R
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:20.04

# Necessary Library
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libharfbuzz-dev \
    libfribidi-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libssl-dev  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Update, Upgrade and Clean
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean

RUN apt-get autoremove -y 

# Working Directory
WORKDIR /app

# Cran Repository
RUN echo 'options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com/"))' >> /etc/R/Rprofile.site

# Install R packages
RUN install.r shiny \
    shinydashboard \
    DT \
    zoo \
    janitor \
    lubridate \
    tidyverse \
    plotly \
    writexl \
    remotes \
    prophet \
    reticulate

# Install and Configure Miniconda
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py310_23.5.2-0-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-py310_23.5.2-0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-py310_23.5.2-0-Linux-x86_64.sh

ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"

# Install tensorflow
RUN conda create --name LSTM python=3.10 tensorflow==2.10.0 -y

# Configure Reticulate to use Conda Environment
RUN R -e 'reticulate::use_condaenv("LSTM")'

# Expose Ports
EXPOSE 3838

# Copy Code into Container
COPY . .

# Make server executable
RUN chmod +x run-server.sh

# Launch Application
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host='0.0.0.0', port=3838)"]
```

I get this error that tensorflow is not found, but I am also using reticulate to point r to the conda environment where tensorflow is installed, using this line `RUN R -e 'reticulate::use_condaenv("LSTM")'`

The `error`

```
Error in library(tensorflow) : there is no package called ‘tensorflow’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
Execution halted
```

What am doing wrong? I need help on this please. Is there anyway to get tensorflow in the environment R environment. I have also tried putting the code below on top of my `global.R` file.
I still get the same error

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv("LSTM", required = TRUE)
```